# Java 7 but not Java 6: "is not abstract and does not override abstract method"

Tags: java, generics, java-7, type-erasure, raw-types

Can someone explain why this compiles in JDK 1.6, but not in JDK 1.7 from which I get the error message:

> java: Example is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable?

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Example implements ScheduledFuture
{
    @Override public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit){ return 0; }
    @Override public int compareTo(Delayed o) { return 0; }
    @Override public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) { return false; }
    @Override public boolean isCancelled() { return false; }
    @Override public boolean isDone() { return false; }
    @Override public Object get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {  return null; }
    @Override public Object get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException { return null; }
}
```

For your information, the methods in this class are generated by IntelliJ after writing just the class declaration.

The error message indicates that the compiler requires that the class declare a compareTo method that takes an `Object` typed parameter and this class takes a `Delayed`.
However, the `ScheduledFuture` interface is defined as extending `Delayed` which in turn extends `Comparable<Delayed>` so to me everything seems to be in order.

If I just change the declaration to

```
private class Example implements ScheduledFuture<Object>
```

it compiles.

I am guessing it has to do with type erasure somehow but I can't really explain it to satisfy myself.

Comment: I in your place would look up the javadoc for ScheduledFuture from 1.6 and 1.7 and check what has changed.

Comment: It happened to me that Java 6 does not prevent raw type inheritance from parametrized classes while 7 does

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't really know why the behaviour changes between [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) and [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) (have you verified that with other compilers? `javac` vs. Eclipse compiler vs. whatever IDEA uses?).

But I can tell you why `compareTo(Delayed)` does **not** implement `compareTo(Object)` when you extend `ScheduledFuture`:

By using `ScheduledFuture`, you're using [a raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it), which means that **all occurances** of generics are pretty much ignored in your class. That means that you're now implementing `Comparable` (and no longer `Comparable<Delayed>`, which in turn means that you need to implement `compareTo(Object)` (the erasure of `Comparable<Delayed>.compareTo()`), but you implement `compareTo(Delayed)`.

**Remember:** Raw types are meant **only** for backwards compatibility. Avoid them in new code at all costs, they do nasty things!

When you change your `extends` clause to `ScheduledFuture<Object>` you "opt-in" to the generics system and the compiler finally realizes (i.e. "is allowed to realize") that your `compareTo(Delayed)` is in fact the proper implementation of the `Comparable<Delayed>` interface.

Comment: +1: This is definitely caused by the use of raw types meaning that all generics are ignored.

Comment: I have only used the Java HotSpot compilers, 1.6.0_43 and 1.7.0_25.

Comment: @ThomasLarssonKron: "HotSpot" is the JVM, it's not the compiler. You've probably used `javac` from those Java versions.